# Start shrew vpn client (iked & ikec) on start-up of OSMC on Raspberry 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn, autostart

I would like to connect to a VPN on start-up of OSMC.

Environment:

- installed [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/download/images/) on Raspberry 2
- downloaded, compiled and installed [shrew soft vpn](https://www.shrew.net/download/ike) on the device
- As user 'osmc' with ssh

  - `> sudo iked` starts the daemon successfully
  - `> ikec -r "test.vpn" -a` starts the client, loads the config and connects successfully
- rc.local:

  `#!/bin/sh -e
  #
  # rc.local
  #
  # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
  # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
  # value on error.
  #
  # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
  # bits.
  #
  # By default this script does nothing.
  sudo iked >> /home/osmc/iked.log 2>> /home/osmc/iked.error.log &
  ikec -a -r "test.vpn" >> /home/osmc/ikec.log 2>> /home/osmc/ikec.error.log &
  exit 0`
- after start of raspberry ike**d** is as process visible with `ps -e`
- but ike**c** is not running
- `osmc@osmc:~$ /etc/rc.local` starts the script and connects to vpn successfully

Problem:

- Why does the script not working correctly on start-up?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking to do the same thing as you and ran into the same problem.  I'm no linux expert, but I did figure out a workaround.

I created a script called ikec_after_reboot.sh and it looks like this...

```
$ cat ikec_after_reboot.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting ikec"
ikec -r test.vpn -a
```

I then installed cron.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cron
```

Edit the cron job as root and run the ikec script 60 seconds after reboot.

```
sudo crontab -e

SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/osmc/ikec_after_reboot.sh & >> /home/osmc/ikec.log 2>&1
```

Now edit your /etc/rc.local file and add the following.

```
sudo iked >> //home/osmc/iked.log 2>> /home/osmc/iked.error.log &
exit 0
```

Hopefully, this is helpful to you.